# Test before changing MySQL column type

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, alter-table

I have a table with a column of type INT(7) and I want to make this a foreign key constraint on the primary key of another table. However, the primary key is type INT(11) UNSIGNED, so I need to change INT(7) to match that in order for the foreign key to be created.

Although I don't expect to have any problems converting an INT(7) to INT(11) UNSIGNED (I have checked the column to be changed and it has no unsigned values), is there any way to ask MySQL which rows it would alter the value of? I will take a backup anyway, but I would like to be able to find out if there are likely to be any problems beforehand as I can potentially fix them before running the ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Maybe do a create newTable as oldTable and make the change on the newTable then do a compare to see where the rows don't match up?    That's the first thing off the top of my head but some of the MySql gurus may know of a better way.

Comment: I did say I would take a backup, however I would like to know beforehand whether any changes will be made. If there are rows which are likely to cause problems I can double-check/fix them before changing the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run

```
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT yourcolumnname AS x, yourcolumnname AS y  FROM yourtable;
ALTER TABLE tmp MODIFY COLUMN x INT(11) UNSIGNED;
SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE x!=y;
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: Very nice solution, will make a note of that for other table modifications as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ALTER TABLE` doesn't commit if the TEMPORARY keyword is used.

```
ALTER TEMPORARY TABLE .... [your code]
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html)

EDIT: I just noticed this:

> "However, although no implicit commit occurs, neither can the
>   statement be rolled back. Therefore, use of such statements will
>   violate transaction atomicity: For example, if you use CREATE
>   TEMPORARY TABLE and then roll back the transaction, the table remains
>   in existence."

So I'm not sure about `ALTER`.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, I just tried it on a development server and the ALTER TABLE is committed immediately - ROLLBACK has no effect (I'm running the stock MySQL provided with Debian, not sure if it has transactions disabled/auto-commit enabled).

Comment: Yes, sorry @pwaring. I don't know what use the `TEMPORARY` keyword is if the transaction cannot be rolled back...

Comment: I don't think you can even use TEMPORARY with ALTER TABLE - the MySQL prompt complains about a syntax error if I do: ALTER TEMPORARY TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [new_type]

Comment: From the mySQL docs: `ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, and DROP TABLE do not commit a transaction if the TEMPORARY keyword is used.` It says all versions.